# Icon android dont appears

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Can someone help me, how I put this icon in my project? [image]

In my project icon doesn't appears and I already change the androidManifest.xml file
Only appears this: [image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ensure in the manifest that the attribute is present in the application tag:
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Answer (score 0):

go to you manifest file and insert this code in `application` tag :

```
    android:icon="@drawable/yourPictureAtDrawable"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file you have to edit the  tag.

In the activity tag add the following:

```
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Java:**

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon);
```

**In XML:**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
       android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" 
       android:label="My new title" />
```